# When the data and variable names change in my function, how should I write them?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to create a function using the quantile function (`quantile`) that can produce the quantile values by cut-points, in the `dplyr` environment.

For example, I want to create a function making the result below.

```
# load library and data 
library(dplyr); library(rlang)
iris <- iris 

cut_points_1 <- c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1) 

quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, cut_points_1)
    0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%   95%  100% 
    4.300 4.800 5.000 5.270 5.600 5.800 6.100 6.300 6.520 6.900 7.255 7.900
```

But, I cannot understand how to manage this part (`iris$Sepal.Length`) in my function. Specifically, I do not know how to call a variable name in a data.frame, when using non-dplyr functions (e.g., `quantile`). In other words, when the names of the `data` and `var_name` change in my function, I do not know how to write `data$var_name` in the function.

Below is my code and function.

```
# load library and data 
library(dplyr); library(rlang)
iris <- iris 

# cut-points (percentage)
cut_points_1 <- c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95,     1) 
cut_points_2 <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)

# function 
cut <- function(data, var_name, cut_points) {
  data <- enquo(data)
  cut_points <- enquo(cut_points)

  varname_cut <- paste0(substitute(var_name), "_cut") # different variable name: source(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131829/unquote-the-variable-name-on-the-right-side-of-mutate-function-in-dplyr/46132317?noredirect=1#comment79234301_46132317)


  !!varname_cut := quantile(!!data$!!var_name, cut_points) # <- This is the problem!
}

# run
cut(iris, Sepal.Length, cut_points_1)
cut(iris, Sepal.Length, cut_points_2)
```

Comment: `!!` and `:=` are intended to be used in dplyr verbs. Why not just try `quantile(data[[var_name]], cut_points)`?

Comment: @mt1022 Then, how can I manage this part? `!!varname_cut := `

Comment: What does that part do? Do you want to create a variable in the global environment? I suggest assign it to a proper name with something like `varname_cut <- quantile(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, adapting your function to make it work :

```r
# load library and data 
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
iris <- iris 

# cut-points (percentage)
cut_points_1 <- c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1) 
cut_points_2 <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)

# function 
cut <- function(data, var_name, cut_points) {
  var_name <- enquo(var_name)
  varname_cut <- paste0(quo_name(var_name), "_cut")
  tibble(cut_points = cut_points,
         !!varname_cut := data %>% pull(!!var_name) %>% quantile(cut_points))
}

# run
cut(iris, Sepal.Length, cut_points_1)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    cut_points Sepal.Length_cut
#>         <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1       0.00            4.300
#>  2       0.10            4.800
#>  3       0.20            5.000
#>  4       0.30            5.270
#>  5       0.40            5.600
#>  6       0.50            5.800
#>  7       0.60            6.100
#>  8       0.70            6.300
#>  9       0.80            6.520
#> 10       0.90            6.900
#> 11       0.95            7.255
#> 12       1.00            7.900
cut(iris, Sepal.Length, cut_points_2)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   cut_points Sepal.Length_cut
#>        <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1        0.0             4.30
#> 2        0.2             5.00
#> 3        0.4             5.60
#> 4        0.6             6.10
#> 5        0.8             6.52
#> 6        1.0             7.90
```

I add a column with cut_points to get something like `quantile` result. You can format it with `%` if needed

#### Some explanation

- You don't need to use `enquo` on `data` and `cut_points` because you don't need quosure in your function for them. They are passed as object.
- you can use `quo_name` to get the name of your quosure to paste it
- You can use `dplyr::pull` to get a column of your data as a vector and no a *one-column* tibble

Comment: Thank you! But, this loop using the above code also gives error: `for (i in 1:2) {cut(iris, Sepal.Length, paste0("cut_points_", i))}` Can I resolve it? @cderv

Comment: One way to iterate over several cut_points would be using `purrr`:
`list(cut_points_1 = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 1), 
     cut_points_2 = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)) %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(~cut(data, Sepal.Length, .x), .id = "cut_point")`

Comment: The problem is that you need to provide the object `cut_points`. In you `for` iteration you provide a string `"cut_points_1"`. You need the object. for example : `cut(iris, Sepal.Length, get(paste0("cut_points_", 1)))` should work