# How do I do Standard evaluation with dplyr's arrange?

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr's `arrange` doesn't seem to work with `!!`

Please see MWE, where I am trying to sort a data.frame by the "date" variable, but instead of using `date` I want to parameterise it using a character/string

```r
library(dplyr)

a = data.frame(date = 1:3, ok = 1:3)

a %>% 
  arrange(date)

date = "date"
a %>% 
  arrange(!!date) # doesn't work


meh = "date"
a %>% 
  arrange(!!meh) # doesn't work
```

I thought `!!` can be used in any dplyr function to perform Standard Evaluation (SE) of the variable. Is the understanding not correct? How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `!!` does not work with arrange but you can still use `get`

```
a %>% arrange(get(meh))


#  date ok
#1    1  1
#2    2  2
#3    3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach (seems a bit roundabout but nevertheless works) is to use `rlang::sym` before applying the unquoting operator:

```
library(dplyr)

a = data.frame(date = 3:1, ok = 1:3)

a %>% 
  arrange(date)

acol = "date"
a %>% 
  arrange(!!rlang::sym(acol))
```

There's also a thorough guide here: [dplyr programming guide](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131829/unquote-the-variable-name-on-the-right-side-of-mutate-function-in-dplyr); basically the same thing.

**Edit** TIL via Diceboy's helpful comment that there are many ways to handle multiple variables:

```
a %>% arrange(get(name1),get(name2))
a %>% arrange(.data[[name1,name2]])
a %>% arrange(!!!rlang::syms(c(name1,name2)))
```

Though `mget` does not work nicely!

Comment: To add to this, `a %>% arrange(!!!syms(meh))` will also work when `meh` is a character vector of length > 1 (i.e. when you want to `arrange` by more than 1 column)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.data` variable:

```
a %>% arrange(.data[[date]])
```

Here are some more examples:

```
aa <- data.frame(date = c(13, 14, 11), ok = 3:1)

# sort by date
date <- "date"
aa %>% arrange(.data[[date]])
##   date ok
## 1   11  1
## 2   13  3
## 3   14  2

# sort by ok
date <- "ok"
aa %>% arrange(.data[[date]])
##   date ok
## 1   11  1
## 2   14  2
## 3   13  3
```