# How to iteratively add to a data frame in R using a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am working on an example for-loop (a reduction of a larger problem I am dealing with), whereby the data frame expands by columns as the for-loop iterates. Here are the results I am trying to get when running the code at the bottom:

```
> data
   x x_1 x_2 x_3
1 10  11  12  13
2 11  12  13  14
3 12  13  14  15
4 13  14  15  16
5 14  15  16  17
6 15  16  17  18
```

However, the below code only manages to iterate through column x_1 before I get the error message *"Error: Problem with mutate() column x_2. i x_2 = x_prior + 1. x non-numeric argument to binary operator"*. What am I doing wrong?

I know there are other ways to generate this data frame but please don't change the overall structure of what I'm doing. I'm trying to learn how to iteratively add columns to the DF whereby the first added column refers back to a base column outside the loop (column `x` in this case), and all columns added after that via the loop refer back to the immediately prior column that was also iteratively generated. I am not too concerned with speed because in practice this loop will never execute > 20 times, so no need for the `apply()` family I think unless there's some magic there. The nice thing about a plodding for-loop is understandability.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(x = 10:15)

for(i in 1:3) {
  x_curnt <- str_c("x_", i)
  x_prior <- str_c("x_",i-1)
  
  data <- if(i==1){
    data %>% mutate(!! x_curnt:= x + 1)} else {
    data %>% mutate(!! x_curnt:= x_prior + 1)
    }
}

data
```

Please don't mark this as a duplicate of [Unquote the variable name on the right side of mutate function in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131829/unquote-the-variable-name-on-the-right-side-of-mutate-function-in-dplyr) because this example is far simpler, and the solution in that post (an old post) doesn't work anymore. Though its solution did help resolve this post.

Comment: Use a matrix if all your values are numeric. I think you will find that advice in “The R Inferno”.

Comment: You could use a base-style approach instead of tidyverse/mutate:
`data[[x_curnt]] <- data[[x_prior]] + 1`

Comment: Essential a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131829/unquote-the-variable-name-on-the-right-side-of-mutate-function-in-dplyr)

Comment: Hmmm Nick I'm looking at that other post but an trying to avoid adding another package. I'll try moving this out of dplyr(mutate) into base R like you suggested, though the larger code this derives from is all in dplyr

Comment: [`dplyr` already imports `rlang`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/DESCRIPTION) so it's not really "adding" another package, per se.

Comment: Oops I mean nwbort suggested a base R approach

Comment: @nwbort is correct. Your problem comes from the fact that `x_prior` is a character, not a “pointer to a column”. You need to tell dplyr what your intentions are. The post newborn has linked to gives you the solution.

Comment: Thanks Limey, I'll fiddle with that post some more. I like the base R solution nbort offers, but it would be good too if I also knew how to do this with dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close with your base R approach. You just needed to:

- remove the assignment by the `if`. This is because in this base R approach, you're just creating a column and not returning the dataframe.
- refer to `data[["x"]]` (or `data$x`) rather than just `x` in the `i=1` case.

Here's a complete working example:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(stringr)


data <- data.frame(x = 10:15)

for(i in 1:3) {
  x_curnt <- str_c("x_", i)
  x_prior <- str_c("x_",i-1)

  if(i==1){
    data[[x_curnt]] <- data[["x"]] + 1
  } else {
    data[[x_curnt]] <- data[[x_prior]] + 1
  }
}

data
#>    x x_1 x_2 x_3
#> 1 10  11  12  13
#> 2 11  12  13  14
#> 3 12  13  14  15
#> 4 13  14  15  16
#> 5 14  15  16  17
#> 6 15  16  17  18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I see nwbort, dumb mistake on my part. Now it's plainly obvious. I'll remove that bungled attempt from the OP because it occupies bytes and adds nothing to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 10:15)

library(tidyverse)
bind_cols(df, map_dfc(1:3, ~transmute(df, !!str_c("x_", .x) := x + .x)))
#>    x x_1 x_2 x_3
#> 1 10  11  12  13
#> 2 11  12  13  14
#> 3 12  13  14  15
#> 4 13  14  15  16
#> 5 14  15  16  17
#> 6 15  16  17  18
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Following nwbort's and Limey's suggestions, I studied the post [Unquote the variable name on the right side of mutate function in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131829/unquote-the-variable-name-on-the-right-side-of-mutate-function-in-dplyr) and it offers a solution. To make this work, the righthand string (the `x_prior` string in my code `x_curnt:= x_prior + 1` above) must be converted to a "quosure", which can be done with `sym()` from the rlang package. So here's revised code that works:

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  x_curnt <- str_c("x_", i)
  x_prior <- str_c("x_",i-1)
  
  data <- if(i==1){
    data %<>% mutate(!! x_curnt:= x + 1)} else {
      data %<>% mutate(!! x_curnt:= !!rlang::sym(x_prior) + 1)
    }
}
```